# javascript select2 with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, jquery-select2

[image]

I am facing an issue in javascript. I want to do display `multiple name` in `select2`. but it is not working

What should I do? Does anyone help me?

**my code:**

```js
savedConfigs.agents_array.map(agent => {   //(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    $('.multipleselect').show();
    for (var i = 0; i < agent.length; i++) {            //not working
        var name = agent.first_name + " " + agent.last_name;
        name != savedConfigs.agent_name ?    //Ayaz Mehmood
            $("#agent-id").append(`<option value="${agent.id}">${name}</option>`) :
            $("#agent-id").append(`<option value="${agent.id}" selected>${name}</option>`)
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="multipleselect" hidden >
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="agent-id" name="agent" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make sure your code does not have any syntax mistake and runnable though it may not give desired value.

Comment: i share a expected output photo [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233959/asutosh)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below one:

```js
savedConfigs = {
  agents_array: [{
    first_name: "agrnt1",
    last_name: "USA"
  }, {
    first_name: "agrnt2",
    last_name: "EU"
  }]
}

savedConfigs.agents_array.map(agent => { //(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  $('.multipleselect').show();
  //not working
  var name = agent.first_name + " " + agent.last_name;
  name != savedConfigs.agent_name ? //Ayaz Mehmood
    $("#agent-id").append(`<option value="${agent.id}">${name}</option>`) :
    $("#agent-id").append(`<option value="${agent.id}" selected>${name}</option>`)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multipleselect" hidden>
  <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="agent-id" name="agent" multiple="multiple">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks i use the same logic but it is not working for multiple value [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233959/asutosh)

Comment: I have added this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/ne3o0d5g/12/

Comment: Use Ctrl key while selcting multiple options

Comment: thanks but it is not working in my code [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233959/asutosh)

Comment: have you removed this ` for (var i = 0; i < agent.length; i++) { ` part, because that's not needed

Comment: yes remove for loop [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233959/asutosh)

Comment: it is too long code [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233959/asutosh)